# attaching data to <td> elements

Tags: jquery

I'm building a web interface to edit values in large tables (2600 x 2600). Because the table is so big, I only load a part of the table into the browser, and the user has the ability to see a small window of the table by specifying xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax values. What is the best way to attach x,y coordinates to each  tag that I display to reflect that cell's actual coordinates in the big table? I've looked into jQuery.data() function but it's not obvious how to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `jQuery.data()` just add attributes to your html markup like so:

```
<td data-x="..." data-y="...">
```

You can then access those values, with:

```
$(element).data('x'); // where element is an td element, you somehow selected
```

Comment: Didn't realise you could do it in markup like that. Good to know. Is it valid XHTML?

Comment: Those are valid HTML5 `data-attribute`s: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes. They are nice to use, very easy. They create a bit more overhead, so if you have lots and lots of elements you will probably want to use `$.data()`.

Comment: @Grim Unfortunately it's only valid in html5. But at least it's well-formed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$.data` is the best method, it's quite a bit faster than `$().data()`:

```
$.data(DOMelement, data-title, data-value);
```

So for instance you can use `this` inside an event handler:

```
$.data(this, 'some-key', 'some-value');
```

The tricky part of `$.data` is that you must use a DOM element as the first argument. Meaning if you have a jQuery object you have to do this:

```
$.data($jQueryObject[0], 'some-key', 'some-value');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends heavily on what you are going to do with this data. Are you often looking for data from an element? Are you often looking for an element based on coordinates?

For performance in a large data set, I would generally use JavaScript - not jQuery. Ideal for only (x, y) data could be using an array, containing indexed data for every each element. Like this:

```
// Each element in array y contains the x index's data object
var y = [ [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}], [{}, {}, {}, { key: 'value' }, {}] ];

// To get the element at (4, 2) (this will be not-so-fast)
// NOTE: There are faster ways to get this element
var xy = $('table tr:eq(1) td:eq(3)');

// To get the data of (4, 2) (this will be super fast)
var dataOfFourThree = y[1][3]; // { key: 'value' }
```

If you have the possibility to reflect DOM data in pure JS, there is always a performance gain to hunt.